# Why does my site have HTTPS in chrome but HTTP in safari?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I'm hosting a site on AWS EC2. I got an SSL certificate using certbot. On Chrome, the site is accessed from HTTPS and the padlock appears. On Safari it says NOT SECURE next to my site's name, and cookies cannot be set (cookies are working in Chrome and they also appear in the Network panel of Safari--they're just not being set because my site isn't secure).

I don't know or understand why my site isn't secure in Safari.

When I click the padlock I can access this certificate (images attached):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also did SSL Server Test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=arriveanywhere.xyz

I got a B grade and it said:

`This server supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. Grade capped to B.`

Additionally, it said I don't have a DNS CAA set up -- could this be my issue?

[image]

Please let me know why it's insecure in Safari but not Chrome...

I have looked around SO, and couldn't find an answer. I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Here is a silly question, just to make sure I understand what you are asking: when you type the address of your web site in safari, you type "https://...", but then it gets swapped for "http://..."?

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Not silly at all... when I added an 's' to http, it appeared encrypted in Safari (!). But it doesn't by default.

Comment: Then the keyword you are looking for is "https redirect". Long story short, your web site can convince any browser to switch to https even if they come in via http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers traditionally default to `http://...` if no explicit method is given (i.e. only domain given). Typically sites will be configured to explicitly redirect `http://` to `https://`, but your site is not configured like this. Still, Chrome will access the site with `https://` anyway since [starting in version 90, Chrome’s address bar will use https:// by default, improving privacy and even loading speed for users visiting websites that support HTTPS](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html). Thus what you see is the new default.

Comment: Chrome also tries http2 by default, which all implementations currently force TLS.

Comment: @jordanm: *"Chrome also tries http2 by default"* - *Trying* is a bit of an exaggeration since it suggests some kind of active detection with fallback if not available. Instead it only *announces* support for http2 by simply adding `h2` to the ALPN extension in the TLS handshake. The server knows from this that the client supports http2 and therefore might use it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ...! That makes sense. Do you have any info on how to configure this redirect?

Comment: @terraforme: *"... how to configure this redirect?"* - Please use a search engine. These information are [easy to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+ec2+redirect+http+to+https).